# Search through compressed/binary plist files in an IPA

Tags: ios, strings

I'm working on an iOS target. I'm effectively interested in running the program and its metadata through strings. I've noticed a simple `grep` does not return expected results and I suspect its because of compressed/binary plist files.

How can I search trough the IPA and dump the key value pairs from a compressed/binary plist?

Comment: You must find out what compression is used. If it is zip, for example, you can use [`zgrep`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_zgrep.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Typically this will use known compression algorithms. Just use [binwalk](http://binwalk.org/) to find the offset and the compression algorithm. Then decompress and dump the strings. Keep in mind that you may want to specify the encoding sometimes, eg:

```
$ string -e l input_file
```